# How can I fix texture clipping in Unreal 4?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

I made a small project testing out mini-maps, it worked fine, I left it alone for a few months and reopened the project, and now I'm getting this:

[image]

I'm not even sure what to call this kind of issue other than clipping.

Also note, a sprite representing the player model is supposed to be at the center of the mini-map, but now it doesn't show. I hadn't made any changes to the project since I last worked on it, and when I check the camera I'm using for the mini-map, the pointer is definitely visible in the Blueprint. The project was made in 4.13.

[image]

Though as I took that screenshot, everything else that should be visible disappeared, so the mini-map no longer is showing the floors and walls. This feels like a graphics problem. Anyone know where I can start fixing this?

**SOLVED: It was a rendering/shader problem. Project settings > platform > mac > rendering > Max Metal Shader Standard to Target = "Metal v1.1"**

Comment: It looks more like a Z-fighting artifact to me. Do you have any polys that are overlapping each other?

Comment: No, all of my objects are flush to each other (that keyboard shortcut is a life-saver).

Comment: Ok so I fixed it, using a setting that solved another problem I had so who knows if that problem will come back. I simply changed the metal shader. Will post solution in main question.

Comment: Glad to see that you solved the problem! Don't forget to [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) - it helps others who may run into the same or similar problems. Also, should you later discover why this change fixes the problem, please edit your answer to include those details. Good luck with your development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** It was a rendering/shader problem. Project settings > platform > mac > rendering > Max Metal Shader Standard to Target = "Metal v1.1"

[image]